# Can't close UWP Backgroundtasks after application terminated

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, background-task, rfcomm

I am trying to add a BT server to my app, and using the "BluetoothRfcommChat" sample project, ("Scenario3_BgChatServer" to be exact  - with background task).
It seems that if I register the background task and terminate the app without unregistering - I cant register again (even after reboot).

How can I kill a UWP background task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Background task registration persists across reboot. You want that to be the case.

If your app wants to renew the registration, you will need to unregister first. You would do this along the lines of:

```
            foreach (var bgTask in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
            {
                if (bgTask.Value.Name == "MaintenanceTask")
                {
                    bgTask.Value.Unregister(true);
                }
            }

            var requestTask = BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
            var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

            builder.Name = "MaintenanceTask";
            builder.TaskEntryPoint = "BackgroundTasks.MaintenanceTask";
            builder.SetTrigger(new MaintenanceTrigger(360, false));
            BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
```